# AJAX request duplicates entire page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am trying to implement chained dependent dropdown combobox selection. I have a 'category' HTML combobox and once the value in there is changed, another combobox should appear to select a subcategory and so on until the innermost (most specific) category is selected. So, whenever the value in the combobox is changed I am firing an AJAX GET request which should reload only that bit of the page, however currently my code just duplicates entire page instead of just creating a new `<select>`.

Here is my Django template with the jQuery code:

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Create a product</h1>
<form method='POST' id='productForm' data-products-url="{% url 'products:ajax_load_categories' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#id_category").change(function () {
  var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-product-url");
  var categoryId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({                       
    url: url,                    
    data: {
      'category': categoryId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#productForm").append(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my view:

```
def load_categories(request):
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    subcategories = Category.objects.get(id=category_id).get_children()
    return render(request, 'products/category_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subcategories': subcategories})
```

Here is my `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', product_create_view, name='product-create'),
    path('ajax/load-categories/', load_categories, name='ajax_load_categories')
]
```

and here is the tiny bit of HTML I am trying to create:

`products/category_dropdown_list_options.html`

```
<select>
    {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
        <option value="{{ subcategory.pk }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Please add this template code of this template file `products/category_dropdown_list_options.html`

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I've added it, just didn't specify it, sorry. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-product-url");`
to `var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");`

Comment: to var url = $("#productForm").attr("data-products-url");

Comment: You forgot an s thus your url is empty/null. It will default to the current url in the browser

Comment: Thanks, can't believe it was a typo.